# Force all floats to appear at top of page

Tags: floats

Is there any easy and global way of forcing all floats (figures, tables etc) to appear on the top of pages only?
Meaning, I want to avoid placing at every figure etc the `[t]` explicitly.

Comment: maybe try `\makeatletter
 \def\fps@figure{t}
 \def\fps@table{t}
\makeatother`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use, as samcarter said in her comment

```
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{t}
\makeatother
```

so that the default for *figures* will be `[t]`. More generally,

```
\makeatletter
\def\fps@<float type>{t}
\makeatother
```

so that the default for *`<float type>`* will be `[t]`.

If you want this to affect *all* floats, then use:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@float#1{%
  \@ifnextchar[%
    {\@xfloat{#1}}%
    {\@xfloat{#1}[t]}}%
\makeatother
```

Both methods will still allow you to use the optional argument to override the default.

---

Note that by doing this you are placing a big restriction on where LaTeX is allowed to place floats, so you might run into trouble. I'd suggest you use at least `tp`, to allow float-only pages, so LaTeX will have some room to work.

Comment: Thanks so much! It seems to work fine for figures and tables, but not for `algorithm2e` or is this a non-floating environment?

Comment: @bonanza Hm... It seems that `algorithm2e` _does_ define a floating environment, but uses some strange argument handling internally. The floating environment is not defined in the "usual" way. Try this and tell me if it worked: `\makeatletter
\edef\algorithm{%
  \noexpand\@protected@testopt\noexpand\algorithm
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname\string\algorithm\endcsname{t}%
}%
\makeatother`

Comment: Works perfectly for algorithm2e, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Load the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float) and specify

```
\floatplacement{<float>}{<specifier>}
```

where `<float>` is a defined float (like `figure`, `table` or defined via `\newfloat`) and `<specifier>` covers what you would specify as the optional parameter to the float (from `!`, `h`ere, `t`op, `b`ottom, `p`age, `H`ERE).